# How to highlight relevant range of number based on input value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to develop an input box with a list of numbers beside and when I enter a number into the input field the javascript/jquery code(I don't know which one would be better solution) highlight(colorize or make it bold style) "live" that list element regarding where to fit the given number.

Here is the example:

[image: Input box with value selector]

Comment: So share you code

Comment: are the numbers on right always the same gap? if so you can take the value from input and do (x -1)/10, for 1 to 10 you get 0, 11 to 20 you get 1, etc. and set the id of lists from 0 to some number, then just select by id to highlight.

Comment: I don't have any code yet just planning to make this works. But if you have any usable code snippet to start it or make it done I would appreciate for it. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisLi Do you have any code for it so I can check how it works?

Comment: @tradingjonah I made a jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Lb7jap3c/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try The following For table**

```js
 $(document).on('keyup','#user-count',function(){
            var SearchedNumber=parseInt($('#user-count').val());
            var Number=$('#user-table tr:not(:first) td:first-child');
            var AllTr=$('#user-table tr:not(:first)');
            var TableBody='';            
            var maxCount= AllTr[AllTr.length-1].innerText.trim().split('+')[0];//get max Count of your Number list
            $('#user-table tbody').empty();
            $.each(Number,function(i,TD){
            var Text=TD.innerText.trim().split('-');
             if(SearchedNumber>=maxCount)//compare max Count
                    {
                     if(i==AllTr.length-1)
                        {
                        TableBody+='<tr style="background-color:#4caf50;font-size:20px"><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[0].innerText+'</td><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[1].innerText+'</td></tr>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                         TableBody+='<tr><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[0].innerText+'</td><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[1].innerText+'</td></tr>';
                        }
                    }
                    else                    
                    {
                     if(SearchedNumber>=Text[0] && SearchedNumber<=Text[1])
               {
                      TableBody+='<tr style="background-color:#4caf50;font-size:20px"><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[0].innerText+'</td><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[1].innerText+'</td></tr>';
               }
               else
               {
                      TableBody+='<tr><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[0].innerText+'</td><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[1].innerText+'</td></tr>';
                }
                    }       
            });
            $('#user-table tbody').append(TableBody);
        });
```

```css
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: #ddd;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.table-striped thead {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-top: 2px solid #c0c0c0;
    color: #404040;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 text-right mt-4">
                      <h5 class="text-center">Users table</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mt-4">
                      <form class="">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <center><input type="number" id="user-count"/></center>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row mt-5 mb-5">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <table class="table table-striped" id="user-table">
                        <thead class="table-striped">
                          <tr>
                            <th>User Count</th>
                            <th class="text-center">Price</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr>
                            <td>0-1</td>
                            <td class="text-center">$1000</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>2-40</td>
                            <td class="text-center">$2000</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>41-250</td>
                            <td class="text-center">$3000</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                            <td>251+</td>
                            <td class="text-center">$4000</td>
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use jquery [`keyup`](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event to running code when key upped on input. In event listener use select all `li` element contain range values and use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to filtering values.

In function check if value of input is in range then return `true` to selecting target `li`.

```js
$(".number-val").keyup(function(){
    var value = this.value;
    $(".number-list li").css("color", "").filter(function(){
        var parts = $(this).text().split("-");    
        return (parseInt(parts[0]) <= value && value <= parseInt(parts[1])) 
    }).css("color", "lightgreen");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>input field of number</p>
<input type="number" class="number-val">
<ul class="number-list">
  <li>1-10</li>
  <li>11-20</li>
  <li>21-40</li>
  <li>41-50</li>
  <li>51-60</li>
  <li>61-80</li>
  <li>81-100</li>
  <li>101-110</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to highlight last number if input value is greater than it, use bottom code:

```js
$(".number-val").on("keyup", function(){
    var value = this.value;
    $(".number-list li").css("color", "").filter(function(){
        var parts = $(this).text().split("-"); 
        parts[1] == "" ? parts[1] = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER : "";
        return (parseInt(parts[0]) <= value && value <= parseInt(parts[1])) 
    }).css("color", "lightgreen");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>input field of number</p>
<input type="number" class="number-val">
<ul class="number-list">
  <li>1-10</li>
  <li>11-20</li>
  <li>21-40</li>
  <li>41-50</li>
  <li>51-60</li>
  <li>61-80</li>
  <li>81-100</li>
  <li>101-</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, it looks great. Is it possible to modify the code if I would like to highlight the last one list element if the input number is bigger than 110?

Comment: Thank you, it is a great, simple code ;) Can you please help to modify the code because if I would like to use the last list element like "101+" the highlighter doesnt works above 101.

Comment: @tradingjonah Check last part of answer and click on `Show code snippet`. It show code snippet for +101

Answer (score 0):

Try This which will show highlight if entered number is greater than max list number

```js
 $(document).on('keyup keydown','#txtNumber',function(){
       var Number=parseInt($('#txtNumber').val());
            var allLi=$('#TestList').find('li');
            $('#TestList').empty();
            var UlBody='';
           var maxCount= allLi[allLi.length-1].innerText.trim().split('-')[0];//get max Count of your Number list
            $.each(allLi,function(i,Li){
              var Text=Li.innerText.trim().split('-');
                    if(Number>=maxCount)//compare max Count
                    {
                     if(i==allLi.length-1)
                        {
                        UlBody+='<li style="color:#4caf50;font-weight: bold;font-size:20px;">'+Li.innerText+'</li>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        UlBody+='<li>'+Li.innerText+'</li>';
                        }
                    }
                    else                    
                    {
                     if(Number>=Text[0] && Number<=Text[1])
                    {
                     UlBody+='<li style="color:#4caf50;font-weight: bold;font-size:20px;">'+Li.innerText+'</li>';
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                     UlBody+='<li>'+Li.innerText+'</li>';
                    }
                    }                       
            });
            $('#TestList').append(UlBody);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="txtNumber" />

<ul id="TestList" style="list-style-type:none">
  <li>1-10</li>
  <li>11-20</li>
  <li>21-40</li>
    <li>41-50</li>
  <li>51-60</li>
  <li>61-80</li>
  <li>81-Plus</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is it possible to modify the code if I would like to highlight the last one list element if the input number is bigger than 81? So the last list element would be 81+

Comment: Can you please help to modify the code because if I would like to use the last list element like "81+" the highlighter doesnt works above 81. And what do you think could it be work with tables? Thanks!

Comment: yes it will be work with table i will post new answare for the table ok

Answer (score 0):

Test it:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#number").change(function(){
    var entry = $("#number").val();
    if ( entry < 0 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".0_minus" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 0 <= entry && entry <= 9 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".0_9" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 10 <= entry && entry <= 19 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".10_19" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 20 <= entry && entry <= 29 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".20_29" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 30 <= entry && entry <= 39 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".30_39" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 40 <= entry && entry <= 49 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".40_49" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 50 <= entry && entry <= 59 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".50_59" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 60 <= entry && entry <= 69 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".60_69" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 70 <= entry && entry <= 79 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".70_79" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 80 <= entry && entry <= 89 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".80_89" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( 90 <= entry && entry <= 99 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".90_99" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    } else if ( entry >= 100 ) {
      $( ".entry" ).remove();
      $( ".100_plus" ).append( "<span class='entry'>"+entry+"</span>" );
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #1a1a1a;
}
.entry {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Demo</legend>
  <label for="height">Number entry:</label>
  <input type="number" id="number" name="Number"
         placeholder="Enter your number..." step="1" />
  <ul>
    <li class="0_minus">Minus 0: </li>
    <li class="0_9">0 - 9: </li>
    <li class="10_19">10 - 19: </li>
    <li class="20_29">20 - 29: </li>
    <li class="30_39">30 - 39: </li>
    <li class="40_49">40 - 49: </li>
    <li class="50_59">50 - 59: </li>
    <li class="60_69">60 - 69: </li>
    <li class="70_79">70 - 79: </li>
    <li class="80_89">80 - 89: </li>
    <li class="90_99">90 - 99: </li>
    <li class="100_plus">100 plus: </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following Code For The table**

```js
$(document).on('keyup','#txtNumber',function(){
    debugger;
       var SearchedNumber=parseInt($('#txtNumber').val());
            var Number=$('#TestTable tr:not(:first) td:first-child');
            var AllTr=$('#TestTable tr:not(:first)');
            var TableBody='';
            $('#TestTable tbody').empty();
            $.each(Number,function(i,TD){
            debugger;
            var Text=TD.innerText.trim().split('-');
            if(SearchedNumber>=Text[0] && SearchedNumber<=Text[1])
      {
                    TableBody+='<tr style="background-color:#4caf50;font-size:20px"><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[0].innerText+'</td><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[1].innerText+'</td><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[2].innerText+'</td></tr>'; 
         }
            else
            {
               TableBody+='<tr><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[0].innerText+'</td><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[1].innerText+'</td><td>'+$(AllTr[i]).find('td')[2].innerText+'</td></tr>'; 
            }
            });   
            $('#TestTable tbody').append(TableBody);   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" id="txtNumber"/>
<br/><br/>
<table border="1" id="TestTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Number</td>
<td>Heading1</td>
<td>Heading2</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>0-10</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>Mumbai</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11-20</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>Pune</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>21-40</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>Navi Mumbai</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>51-60</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>Panvel</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. If I trying to use it with bootstrap table and insert a number in the input field all the rows are disapper from the table. What can cause this issue?

Comment: Here is my code and if you put a number in the input box the table content will disappear. http://jsfiddle.net/wLnms9dp/16

Comment: there is simple error While Creating a TableBody ,In that variable u creating 3 <td>& in your table there is only 2 <td>  See the answare i Posting now

Answer (score 0):

**Try This for highlighter doesnt works above last Number**

```js
   $(document).on('keyup keydown','#txtNumber',function(){
       var Number=parseInt($('#txtNumber').val());
            var allLi=$('#TestList').find('li');
            $('#TestList').empty();
            var UlBody='';
            $.each(allLi,function(i,Li){
              var Text=Li.innerText.trim().split('-');
                     if(Number>=Text[0] && Number<=Text[1])
                        {
                        UlBody+='<li style="color:#4caf50;font-weight: bold;font-size:20px;">'+Li.innerText+'</li>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                        UlBody+='<li>'+Li.innerText+'</li>';
                        }                         
            });
            $('#TestList').append(UlBody);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id="txtNumber" />

<ul id="TestList" style="list-style-type:none">
  <li>1-10</li>
  <li>11-20</li>
  <li>21-40</li>
    <li>41-50</li>
  <li>51-60</li>
  <li>61-81</li>
</ul>
```